# how to get the lists of variable stored in 6 lines into one list and eliminate empty lists

Tags: python, list, search, merge, newline

```py
l = []\n['Channels', ':']\n[]\n['AN1', 'AN2']\n[]\n['10v', '0.01V']\n[]
```

Output should be like this: `l = ['Channels',':','AN1','AN2','10v', '0.01V]`

How can I get them in one single list eliminating empty lists.

Comment: `l = []\n['Channels', ':']\n[]\n['AN1', 'AN2']\n[]\n['10v', '0.01V']\n[]` is a `string` ??

Answer (score 1):

```
l= "[]\n['Channels', ':']\n[]\n['AN1', 'AN2']\n[]\n['10v', '0.01V']\n[]"
print(l.split("'")[1::2])
```

Comment: Attribite error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: is your `l` variable a string?

Comment: its type is list stored in a variable.

Comment: i mean 'l' is variable in which is stored with 6 lists i newlines

Comment: could you post a code how you construct `l` variable?

Comment: Given the inclusion of the `\n` characters in `l`, I would think the only possible type for `l` is a string

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your list of variables is a string.

```
import re 

l = "[]\n['Channels', ':']\n[]\n['AN1', 'AN2']\n[]\n['10v', '0.01V']\n[]"

full = re.compile(r"\[.+\]")
results = [] 
for element in full.findall(l):
    results += eval(element)

print(results)
```